# nginx reverse proxy multiple locations

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I want to make a reverse proxy for multiple applications.
Something like this:

```
https://proxyip/app1 -> https://10.10.0.1/
https://proxyip/app2 -> https://10.10.0.2/
etc.
```

Currently, my config is:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name _;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/cert.key;

    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    Host                    $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto       $scheme;

    client_max_body_size 0;

    error_log   syslog:server=unix:/dev/log;
    access_log  syslog:server=unix:/dev/log;

    location /app1/ {
        proxy_pass https://10.10.0.1/;
    }

    location /app2/ {
        proxy_pass https://10.10.0.2/;
    }

    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

But nothing works.
When I go to `https://proxyip/app1` it redirects me to `https://proxyip/Account/login` and I'm getting 404. It should go to `https://proxyip/app1/Account/login`.
Here is logs:

```
Jun 06 15:05:44 my_proxy nginx[3829]: my_proxy nginx: 192.168.0.10 - - [06/Jun/2017:15:05:44 +0300] "GET /app1 HTTP/1.1" 301 185 "-" "BrowserUserAgent"
Jun 06 15:05:44 my_proxy nginx[3829]: my_proxy nginx: 192.168.0.10 - - [06/Jun/2017:15:05:44 +0300] "GET /app1/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "BrowserUserAgent"
Jun 06 15:05:44 my_proxy nginx[3829]: my_proxy nginx: 192.168.0.10 - - [06/Jun/2017:15:05:44 +0300] "GET /Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F HTTP/1.1" 404 571 "-" "BrowserUserAgent"
Jun 06 15:16:32 my_proxy nginx[3829]: my_proxy nginx: 192.168.0.10 - - [06/Jun/2017:15:16:32 +0300] "GET /app1 HTTP/1.1" 301 185 "-" "BrowserUserAgent"
Jun 06 15:16:32 my_proxy nginx[3829]: my_proxy nginx: 192.168.0.10 - - [06/Jun/2017:15:16:32 +0300] "GET /app1/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "BrowserUserAgent"
Jun 06 15:16:32 my_proxy nginx[3829]: my_proxy nginx: 192.168.0.10 - - [06/Jun/2017:15:16:32 +0300] "GET /Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F HTTP/1.1" 404 571 "-" "BrowserUserAgent"
```

When I'm removing trailing `/` from proxy_pass, I'm getting 404 from application itself.
Logs:

```
Jun 06 15:21:42 my_proxy nginx[3829]: my_proxy nginx: 192.168.0.10 - - [06/Jun/2017:15:21:42 +0300] "GET /app1 HTTP/1.1" 301 185 "-" "BrowserUserAgent"
Jun 06 15:21:52 my_proxy nginx[3829]: my_proxy nginx: 192.168.0.10 - - [06/Jun/2017:15:21:52 +0300] "GET /app1/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1831 "-" "BrowserUserAgent"
Jun 06 15:21:52 my_proxy nginx[3829]: my_proxy nginx: 192.168.0.10 - - [06/Jun/2017:15:21:52 +0300] "GET /Content/bundleCss HTTP/1.1" 404 571 "https://proxyip/app1/" "BrowserUserAgent"
Jun 06 15:21:52 my_proxy nginx[3829]: my_proxy nginx: 192.168.0.10 - - [06/Jun/2017:15:21:52 +0300] "GET /Content/themes/base/jquery HTTP/1.1" 404 571 "https://proxyip/app1/" "BrowserUserAgent"
Jun 06 15:21:52 my_proxy nginx[3829]: my_proxy nginx: 192.168.0.10 - - [06/Jun/2017:15:21:52 +0300] "GET /bundles/jquery HTTP/1.1" 404 571 "https://proxyip/app1/" "BrowserUserAgent"
Jun 06 15:21:52 my_proxy nginx[3829]: my_proxy nginx: 192.168.0.10 - - [06/Jun/2017:15:21:52 +0300] "GET /bundles/bootstrap HTTP/1.1" 404 571 "https://proxyip/app1/" "BrowserUserAgent"
Jun 06 15:21:52 my_proxy nginx[3829]: my_proxy nginx: 192.168.0.10 - - [06/Jun/2017:15:21:52 +0300] "GET /bundles/extlibs HTTP/1.1" 404 571 "https://proxyip/app1/" "BrowserUserAgent"
```

Can you help me?

to @Tero-Kilkanen:
I've tried as you said:

```
location ~^/app1(.*)$ {
proxy_pass https://10.10.0.1$1;
}
```

But still nothing. Here is logs:

```
Jun 08 10:07:33 my-proxy nginx[8882]: my-proxy nginx: 192.168.0.10 - - [08/Jun/2017:10:07:33 +0300] "GET /app1 HTTP/1.1" 404 1831 "-" "UserAgent"
Jun 08 10:07:33 my-proxy nginx[8882]: my-proxy nginx: 192.168.0.10 - - [08/Jun/2017:10:07:33 +0300] "GET /Content/bundleCss HTTP/1.1" 404 571 "https://10.10.0.1/app1" "UserAgent"
Jun 08 10:07:33 my-proxy nginx[8882]: my-proxy nginx: 192.168.0.10 - - [08/Jun/2017:10:07:33 +0300] "GET /bundles/modernizr HTTP/1.1" 404 571 "https://10.10.0.1/app1" "UserAgent"
Jun 08 10:07:33 my-proxy nginx[8882]: my-proxy nginx: 192.168.0.10 - - [08/Jun/2017:10:07:33 +0300] "GET /bundles/jquery HTTP/1.1" 404 571 "https://10.10.0.1/app1" "UserAgent"
Jun 08 10:07:33 my-proxy nginx[8882]: my-proxy nginx: 192.168.0.10 - - [08/Jun/2017:10:07:33 +0300] "GET /bundles/bootstrap HTTP/1.1" 404 571 "https://10.10.0.1/app1" "UserAgent"
Jun 08 10:07:33 my-proxy nginx[8882]: my-proxy nginx: 192.168.0.10 - - [08/Jun/2017:10:07:33 +0300] "GET /bundles/extlibs HTTP/1.1" 404 571 "https://10.10.0.1/app1" "UserAgent"
Jun 08 10:07:33 my-proxy nginx[8882]: my-proxy nginx: 192.168.0.10 - - [08/Jun/2017:10:07:33 +0300] "GET /Content/themes/base/jquery HTTP/1.1" 404 571 "https://10.10.0.1/app1" "UserAgent"
Jun 08 10:07:33 my-proxy nginx[8882]: my-proxy nginx: 192.168.0.10 - - [08/Jun/2017:10:07:33 +0300] "GET /bundles/jquery HTTP/1.1" 404 571 "https://10.10.0.1/app1" "UserAgent"
Jun 08 10:07:33 my-proxy nginx[8882]: my-proxy nginx: 192.168.0.10 - - [08/Jun/2017:10:07:33 +0300] "GET /bundles/bootstrap HTTP/1.1" 404 571 "https://10.10.0.1/app1" "UserAgent"
Jun 08 10:07:33 my-proxy nginx[8882]: my-proxy nginx: 192.168.0.10 - - [08/Jun/2017:10:07:33 +0300] "GET /bundles/extlibs HTTP/1.1" 404 571 "https://10.10.0.1/app1" "UserAgent"
```

Application IIS logs on error:

```
2017-06-08 12:41:27.264 /Error/NotFound - "E:\wwwroot\MyAppPool\Error\NotFound" 404 "app-server" - 0 2105 587
2017-06-08 12:41:27.264 /app1 - "E:\wwwroot\MyAppPool\app1" 404 "app-server" - 0 2105 587
```

Application IIS logs when connecting sucessfully (without proxy):

```
2017-06-09 06:46:36.934 / - "E:\wwwroot\MyAppPool" 302 "app-server" - 0 267 612
2017-06-09 06:46:44.673 /Account/Login ReturnUrl=%2F "E:\wwwroot\MyAppPool\Account\Login" 200 "app-server" - 0 17530 743
2017-06-09 06:46:44.878 /bundles/modernizr v=inCVuEFe6J4Q07A0AcRsbJic_UE5MwpRMNGcOtk94TE1 "E:\wwwroot\MyAppPool\bundles\modernizr" 200 "app-server" "https://10.10.0.1/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F" 0 11477 634
2017-06-09 06:46:44.892 /bundles/jquery v=Z_3sx_Om2qdGQNW4A5Csgy0WZLaXSa4Eg8ukUl26_Qw1 "E:\wwwroot\MyAppPool\bundles\jquery" 200 "app-server" "https://10.10.0.1/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F" 0 96542 631
2017-06-09 06:46:44.905 /Scripts/app/signatureHelper.js - "E:\wwwroot\MyAppPool\Scripts\app\signatureHelper.js" 200 "app-server" "https://10.10.0.1/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F" 0 10309 600
2017-06-09 06:46:44.920 /bundles/bootstrap v=H2j5HUSj46jlSq1Se76I-uTAYq6y_MryNeOkhmo3adE1 "E:\wwwroot\MyAppPool\bundles\bootstrap" 200 "app-server" "https://10.10.0.1/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F" 0 40031 634
2017-06-09 06:46:45.234 /Content/bundleCss v=QR3LEdUKMTwhOusb6Ic-dRnsOi-C89Qfl8hxv_73Pr41 "E:\wwwroot\MyAppPool\Content\bundleCss" 200 "app-server" "https://10.10.0.1/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F" 0 679954 649
2017-06-09 06:46:45.417 /Content/themes/base/jquery v=GZKJzOOlsTUy2AD4HAw4TdqockAuF9srZRUOXVJLoJQ1 "E:\wwwroot\MyAppPool\Content\themes\base\jquery" 200 "app-server" "https://10.10.0.1/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F" 0 45215 658
2017-06-09 06:46:45.456 /bundles/extlibs v=4Ziz4fY8b9xGa5ThFN7ipb8OedxUWcMRvcf0slVL57E1 "E:\wwwroot\MyAppPool\bundles\extlibs" 200 "app-server" "https://10.10.0.1/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F" 0 6293867 632
2017-06-09 06:46:46.451 /fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff - "E:\wwwroot\MyAppPool\fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff" 200 "app-server" "https://10.10.0.1/Content/bundleCss?v=QR3LEdUKMTwhOusb6Ic-dRnsOi-C89Qfl8hxv_73Pr41" 0 23690 676
```

Comment: Remove last / in proxy_pass directive.

Comment: As i mentioned, removal of trailing / doesn't helps. Second block of logs is showing this.

Comment: Can you show application logs? One issue might be that it doesn't receive the correct `Host:` header and therefore it fails.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen I've added IIS logs.

Comment: And how does IIS log files look with succesful requests directly to the server?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Updated post with successful login IIS logs.

Comment: Does your IIS respond correctly when you access the site via IP address?

Comment: Yes. Application itself works great. But no luck through nginx.

Answer (score 10):

nginx proxy_pass [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) states that when `proxy_pass` is specified with an URI, then the proxy_pass destination is used and the path in `location` is not used.

Example:

```
location /app1 {
    proxy_pass http://proxy.example.com/app1;
}
```

With this configuration, all requests that begin with `http://example.com/app1` will end up to `http://proxy.example.com/app1`. This includes `http://example.com/app1/dir1`.

The solution to fix this is to use regular expression capture in the `location` directive, and use the captured variable in `proxy_pass` destination, like this:

```
location ~ ^/app1(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass http://proxy.example.com$1;
}
```

This will make nginx append the string after `app1` to the `proxy_pass` destination line.

Comment: Still nothing. Added additional logs to my question.

Comment: Thanks, Tero! This helped me save time!

Answer (score 1):

Your setup should work without the last slash / in proxy_pass directive.

One thing that you need to consider is that when the proxy traffic is passed the location path will be passed as well, meaning when someone requests:

https://proxyip/app1, nginx will request the following url from the backend: https://10.10.0.1/app1

Which will result in:

```
https://proxyip/app1  => https://10.10.0.1/app1 
https://proxyip/app2  => https://10.10.0.2/app2
```

The solution here will be:

1. Create custom rewirte configuration on your backend server where you will rewrite appX to /
2. Move your app into the corresponding sub folder for the specific location of the backend server.

Comment: Isn't trailing `/` should work as this?  `https://proxyip/app1 -> https://10.10.0.1/`

Comment: As far as i can understand logs, trailing `/` works, browser understands that it should get login page, but then all requests goes not to `https://10.10.0.1/Account/Login` but to `https://proxyip/Account/Login`.

Answer (score 1):

The below should serve the purpose as desired by you:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/cert.key;

    server_name _;
    location /app1 {
        rewrite /app1/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect   off;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass https://10.10.0.1/;

    }   
}
```